# SharePoint online,creating workflow in SPD 2013 'approvment email'

Tags: workflow, office365, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

How I can create email approvment when file adding to the list in SHarePoint online? 
And the second question how I can add buttons with Approve/Reject to the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. See [this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/All-about-Approval-workflows-078c5a89-821f-44a9-9530-40bb34f9f742#add1add) for how to create a basic Approval workflow
   for a document library.
2. As part of that process, you will select a Task list that will be
   used to store the Approval Tasks assigned to the workflow
   participants.
   [image]
3. Navigate to the Task list selected and under List Settings >
   Advanced Settings, select 'Yes' to send an email when ownership
   assigned.